# Прерывании функции с циклом for Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть событие которые навешано на кнопку:

```
 $(" div.btn_submit_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>").on('click', function(outer){
        var formID = $(this).attr('formID');
        $('.files-box_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>').append($('.bids_form_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?> .files-block').detach());
        for (index = 0; index < sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>.length; ++index) {
      $('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[name='" + sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].now + "']").val($(sopArray_<?=$_REQUEST['CODE']?>[index].orig).val());
      if ( false ) {
          break function(outer);
}} $('.form_id_'+formID).find("input[type='submit']").click();

    });
```

Как остановить выполнение функции при условии наличии в форме ввода пустых значений. Что типо такого:

```
if ( false ) {
      break function(outer);}
```

Comment: У вас XSS там где `$_REQUEST['CODE']`

Comment: @sanmai Какой XSS?? ничего подобного, сайт продажи неликвидов на предприятии

Comment: В `$_REQUEST['CODE']` можно подать код, который выполнится у вас на сайте. Это XSS.

Comment: `if (false) return false;`

Comment: Например: `$_REQUEST['CODE'] = '");  alert("XSS"); $("';`